# Android - Changing one xml id changes another

Tags: java, android

For some reason when I change the id of some buttons in xml files it changes the name of buttons in other xml files, this breaks the program, can someone explain what is happening here, are they perhaps linked somehow?

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/third_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background_with_touch"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gift"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/keep"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gift_jewellery_but" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gift"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:background="@drawable/jewellery_self_but" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/third_page"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background_with_touch"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/existing_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/receiver"
        android:layout_below="@+id/receiver"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:background="@drawable/generic_button"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Do you have jewellery you want to upload a message to? \n (Are you a sender?)"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/about_kiroco"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/existing_user"
        android:layout_below="@+id/existing_user"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:background="@drawable/generic_button"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="I&apos;m not sure. I just want to try out my new jewellery. \n (Test Drive the Jewellery)"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/receiver"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
        android:background="@drawable/generic_button"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:minWidth="60dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Do you have jewellery you want to receive a message from? \n (Are you a receiver?)"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Those are two files where if I change the id of the layout of one it changes the name of the other to match it.

Comment: Sorry am adding it now.

Comment: I think you are using rename refactoring. If so, try to do it manually from xml.

Comment: Yes I am using refactoring, I thought that was the proper way to do it?

Comment: Thank, you I solved it by not refactoring like you said.